# Can 'install4j' be renamed on 'Request Privileges' action?

Tags: install4j

My install4j installer requires admin privileges. I've noticed that when it runs the 'Request privileges' action on a Mac it brings up a pop-up saying :

install4j wants to make changes...

Is it possible to rename this so that it reads:

MyApp wants to make changes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of install4j 7.x, this prompt is not configurable, I've created an issue for it.